# Individual JSON field to PHP array

Tags: javascript, json

I'm dealing with bootstrap tables and have this script:

```
<script>
var $table = $('#table'),
$button = $('#button');

$(function () {
    $button.click(function () {

        alert('getSelections: ' +  JSON.stringify($table.bootstrapTable('getSelections')));
    });
});
```

That function gives me this for example:

```
    getSelections: [
  {
    "state": true,
    "_state_data": {},
    "name": "google",
    "_name_data": {},
    "endung": "de",
    "_endung_data": {},
    "regdatum": "2012-03-14 00:00:00",
    "_regdatum_data": {},
    "tags": "kunde wolli test ",
    "_tags_data": {},
    "id": "1",
    "_id_data": {}
  },
  {
    "state": true,
    "_state_data": {},
    "name": "prosite",
    "_name_data": {},
    "endung": "de",
    "_endung_data": {},
    "regdatum": "2015-01-02 00:00:00",
    "_regdatum_data": {},
    "tags": "",
    "_tags_data": {},
    "id": "3",
    "_id_data": {}
  }
]
```

Now I don't want to get the alert, I need to  get only the ID fields and pass them to an PHP array to go on. Unfortunately I'm too dumb for javascript.

```
var selection = JSON.stringify($table.bootstrapTable('getSelections'));

console.log(selection);
```

shows me the correct selection.

```
console.log(selection.id);
```

is undefined

Comment: You are essentially asking two questions here: **1.** How to extract an individual value from each object in an array. **2.** Sending data to the server. Can you please show us what you have tried thus far?

Comment: Problem is, that i really don't know javascript. For 1. i tried this
   foreach ($result['table'] as $key => $value) {
                echo $value['name'].','.$value['id'];
            }

Comment: Looks to me like you are mixing up your JS and PHP... Why don't we leave the serverside communication for now and focus on the JS issue. Do you have any JS attempts to extract the `id` attribute?

Comment: foreach ($result[$table.bootstrapTable('getSelections')] as $key => $value) {
                echo $value['name'].','.$value['id'];
            }
            alert(JSON.stringify($result));

[Error] SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'as'. Expected ')' to end a argument list.

Comment: As I said before, you are mixing JavaScript and PHP. `echo` is a PHP command and `alert` is a JavaScript command. Please also include these attempts in your original post

Comment: Maybe because like i said before, i don't know javascript?! I found that code snippet here on sof. The original post is a good point to start because i am getting all data. Now i just want to have the id fields.

Comment: var selection = JSON.stringify($table.bootstrapTable('getSelections'));

$.each(selection, function(key,value){
   console.log(key + ' ' + value);
});


gives me

TypeError: [{"state":true,"_state_data":{},"name":"prosite","_name_data":{},"endung":"de","_endung_data":{},"regdatum":"2015-01-02 00:00:00","_regdatum_data":{},"tags":"","_tags_data":{},"id":"3","_id_data":{}}] is not a valid argument for 'in' (evaluating '( length - 1 ) in obj')

Comment: `$.each` expects the argument to be an array or object, not a string. You are passing a string, that's why you get the error. Don't call `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: Thank you.. now i am getting my ids only :)